# Visual Basic Windows media player: Changing current time

Tags: vb.net, windows-media-player

Im using a trackbar to change the current time position of the video displayed on a windows media player.

The trackbar maximum value is whatever the length (in seconds) of the video is.

So i need help with how to change the current time on a windows media player.

I am not having difficulty i just need to know how to do it.

Im not sure if there are several ways to embed windows media player into vb, so im just gonna clarify that i didnt install/download anything i just used the one that came with windows media player.

Comment: What part of the WMP control's API are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @iaintrllingyou How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use The [currentPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564740(v=vs.85).aspx) property of CtlControls.

```
player.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = CDbl(10.4)
```